# Current in solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism

Why the total current of solenoid is given by **nI** (where n is total number of turns) and not only the I as in most of the cases

Answer (score 0):

$nI$ is not the total current. Its called ampere turns and the magnetic field intensity is directly proportional to it as more the ampere turns, more the magnetic field intensity.

Comment: Also check the meaning of "n".  As I recall, it's turns per meter, not total number of turns.

Comment: @DavidWhite absolutely